# mod_rewrite for multiple requests not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Perhaps someone can help me with this before I go completely crazy with it. I have a site with two urls which I want to redirect.

I want all traffic except the gallery pages to go to index.php.

This is my htaccess:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1

RewriteRule ^gallery(/((([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(/(\d+))?)/?)?)?$ gallery.php?groupId=$4&showpage=$6 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This works except for one part. The rewrite rule for the gallery is not fully working. It is sending through the groupId to the gallery.php script but I am not getting through the showpage argument. In fact when the showpage is included in the url I get a 404. So for instance.

These work and are handled correctly by the rewrite rule

```
gallery

gallery/

gallery/mygroup

gallery/mygroup/
```

This does not work and throws 404's.

```
gallery/mygroup/2
```

Nothing I do seems to fix this and I would appreciate your help on this. If I set the showpage. The gallery script works if I feed it the old

```
gallery.php?groupId=mygroup&showpage=2
```

so I am sure the htaccess rule is not catching the url.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex seems a little over-the-top.  Use two simpler rewrite rules instead:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ gallery.php?groupId=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^gallery/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(\d+)/?$ gallery.php?groupId=$1&showpage=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```